# Remove a React component from the DOM

Tags: reactjs

I have this piece of code (which I've simplified for posting here) that creates a component and renders it

```
        const getComponentToRender = (user, path) => {
          switch(path ){
            case 'ChangePassword':
              return <ChangePassword user={ user } />;
            case 'NewPassword':
              return <NewPassword user={ user } />;
            case 'PasswordExpire':
              return <PasswordExpire user={ user } />;
            default:
              return null;
          }
         }

        class UserAdmin extends React.Component {  
          static propTypes = {
            user: PropTypes.object.isRequired
          };
          render() {
            const component = getComponentToRender(this.props.user, 'ChangePassword' );          
            return(
                <div id='user-admin-wrapper'>
                  {component}
                </div>
              )

          }  
          componentWillUnmount(){

          }
       }
```

When I navigate away from UserAdmin the `componentWillUnmount` gets called.

Q: What is the simplest way to actually remove the component `ChangePassword` or any other component (by its name) from the DOM when `componentWillUnmount` executes.
**OR**, removing the component at any point, without waiting for `componentWillUnmount`

Using react-dom 15.6.1 . btw

Answer (score 1):

Un-mounting a component will un-mount(remove) all the child components it contains. So after `componentWillUnmount` the component you rendered inside it will be removed.

If you need to control over components that rendered without un-mounting you use conditional render logic.

**Example**

```
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      shouldIRender: true
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.setState({shouldIRender: false});
    }, 5000);
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div>
        <ComponentThatAlwaysHere />
        { this.state.shouldIRender === true ? <ComponentThatRemovesAfterStateChange /> : null }
        { this.state.shouldIRender === true && <AnotherComponentThatRemovesAfterStateChange /> }
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```